# Is Oracle Wallet available for use with Oracle XE 11gR1

Tags: oracle

Oracle XE 11gR1
RHEL 6.3

Is Oracle Wallet available with Oracle XE for production environments? or any environment?
Google search turns up nothing specifically declaring it not being available.

Comment: ask an Oracle licencing rep. it's the only way to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#XELIC116

**Options and Major Features Not Included**

```
Security

Advanced Security Option
...
Secure External Password Store
SecureFiles Encryption
```

**Availability/Backup and Recovery Features**

```
Backup Encryption No
```

The technologies that use the wallet are excluded, so the answer is no. Oracle Express Edition does not include the wallet management tools (mkstore, orapki, owm) at all.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Oracle Database Licensing Information 11g Release 2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e47877.pdf) document

> **Oracle Wallet**
>
> An Oracle Wallet is a PKCS#12 container used to store
> authentication and encryption keys. The Oracle database secure
> external password store feature stores passwords in an Oracle Wallet
> for password-based authentication to the Oracle database. The Oracle
> Wallet may also be used to store credentials for PKI authentication to
> the Oracle Database, configuration of network encryption (SSL/TLS),
> and Oracle Advanced Security transparent data encryption (TDE) master
> encryption keys. ***Strong authentication services (Kerberos, PKI, and
> RADIUS) and network encryption (native network encryption and SSL/TLS)
> are no longer part of Oracle Advanced Security and are available in
> all licensed editions of all supported releases of the Oracle
> database***.

That last bit about strong authentication services and network encryption being available in all licensed and supported releases of the Oracle database would suggest that it might be.  It just a matter how licensed and supported are defined.  XE is licensed, but it's support is via Oracle's [free discussion forum](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/oracle_database_express_edition_xe) rather than via the paid for My Oracle Support site

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Wallet is not available with Oracle XE per se but can be deployed with any Oracle version.  That is to say, I can create a wallet on a licensed version of Oracle only.  But a wallet can be deployed free of charge on any version.

There is also the option of using openSSL.  After getting a certificate, run the following to create your wallet:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycertCA.pem -out ewallet.p12 -nokeys
```

You will also be prompted with the chance to add a password after running the above.